# Plug and Play Condenser Mic not working on my USB Mixer Interface

Tags: microphone, mixer, audio-interfaces

I recently bought a **new condenser microphone** online to replace my old **BM800**. My problem is, the new condenser mic only works when directly plugged into my pc with the 3.5mm TRS connector. It does not work when plugged into my **Ammoon AM-4R** usb mixer interface. I tried connecting with Phantom Power (+48V) and without Phantom Power. I am using male-female XLR cable to connect the new mic to my usb mixer interface. I checked the XLR cables and is working fine with consistent output of +48V when Phantom Power is on. Is there something I'm missing here? I really want this mic to work using my usb mixer interface and not while directly plugged into my pc. The seller doesn't seem to know why it is not working and can't provide any solution either. Thanks a lot for answering.

This is the specs of the new condenser mic that I bought:
[image]

Comment: We don't have much to go on. You're armed with as much data as it's possible to gather, short of swapping each element of the rig one at a time to determine which bit has failed. If the seller can't tell you, neither can we. Send it back.

Comment: This looks like a fault troubleshooting issue - which we cannot do here. Other than swapping components in and out to find out which one is faulty, simplest option is to return the mic.